# Build from Dockerfile-runtime Import h2o4gpu - No h2o4gpu Module

Tags: h2o, h2o4gpu

I have recently built the h2o4gpu docker image using the Dockerfile-runtime, and managed to run it and log into the Jupyter notebooks.

However, when trying to run

```
import h2o4gpu
```

I get the error that there is no h2o4gpu module. After, I tried installing by adding the below command to the dockerfile.

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.anaconda.org/gpuopenanalytics/simple h2o4gpu 
pip install h2o4gpu-0.2.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

This also failed, so I was wondering if there were other changes I should make, or if I should be making the docker file from scratch.

Thank you

Comment: The way we're making our docker images is a bit convoluted, I'm working this week on simplifying it and making it a bit more user friendly. For the time being have you tried one of the images we link to in the README on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the project, you can follow this recipe:

```
git clone https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu.git
cd h2o4gpu
make centos7_cuda9_in_docker
```

This will work on either an x86_64 or ppc64le host with a modern docker installed.
The python .whl file artifact is written to the `dist` directory.

Even if the build process is significantly refactored, this style of build API is very likely to remain.

Comment: The make steps got further, but have prompted two more questions:

1. If I get "Step 1/55 : FROM undefined" is that because I am missing CUDA drivers?

2. Do I need the latest "wget", I am getting a SSL error on another machine when using wget (version 11.14) to sourceforge

Comment: The FROM is nvidia/cuda:9.0-cudnn7-devel-centos7